# Passing an ArrayList of LatLng through intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

Right now, I know how to send an `ArrayList` of `Strings` through `intent` by doing this to send:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list", list);
startActivity(intent);
```

and this to receive:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
ArrayList<String> list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("list");
```

But I want to send an ArrayList of LatLngs, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
intent.putLatLngArrayListExtra("listLatLng", listLatLng);
startActivity(intent);
\\pseudo code, obviously
```

and then:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
ArrayList<String> list = i.getLatLngArrayListExtra("listLatLng");
\\pseudo code, obviously
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Is there any easy way or do I have to modify something? Thanks.

Comment: you want to use `putParcelableArrayListExtra`

Comment: as simple as that, or do I need to do anything else? What is Parceable, exactly?

Comment: if `LatLng` does not extend `Parcelable` (i believe it does) then you will need to create a class that extends Parcelable and hold the values

Comment: Location is definately pacrelable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use android.location;  It extends Parcelable and you can easily create and store the Locations in an arrayList created from lat and lon values

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
         i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(name, value);
```